# Mean Value Theorem with second derivative without using Lagrange Remainder

Tags: real-analysis

> For $h > 0$ let $I = [x - h, x + h]$ and  $$g(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - 2f(x) + f(x - h)}{h^2}.$$
> If $f \in C^2(I)$, show that $\exists \zeta \in (x - h, x + h) \colon g(x) = f''(\zeta)$.

My solution thus far:

Using the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists b \in (x, x + h)$ and $\exists a \in (x - h, x) \colon$
$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(b) \text{ and } \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h} = f'(a)$$
$\implies \exists \zeta \in (x - h, x + h) \colon$
$$\frac{f'(b) - f'(a)}{b - a} = \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{(b - a) \cdot h} = f''(\zeta).$$
How can I go from $(b - a) \cdot h$ to $h^2$ without using Lagrange Remainder?

Comment: You will essentially have to repeat the proof of Lagrange remainder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote with $M(x):= \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$, then you have $g(x) = \frac{M(x)-M(x-h)}h$. By the mean value theorem you get a $\xi\in (x-h,x)$ with
$$g(x) = M'(\xi)=\frac{f'(\xi+h)-f'(\xi)}{h}$$
apply the mean value theorem again to get a $\zeta\in ( \xi,\xi+h)\subseteq (x-h,x+h)$ with
$$g(x) = f''(\zeta)$$